# A question about Golden - Thompson inequality

Tags: matrices

Given two hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, the Golden - Thompson inequality states:
$$tr\left(e^{(A+B)}\right)\le tr\left(e^Ae^B\right)$$
My question is: when the two traces are equal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for the identity is $[A,B]=0$.

Comment: Well, at least a sufficiant condition is $[A,B]=0$. But it's not even necessary for $e^{(A+B)}=e^Ae^B$

Comment: @roman: $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian, so it is necessary